# How would I setup Joomla to require or bypass authentication based on visitors IP address?

Tags: apache, joomla, ldap

How would I setup Joomla to require or bypass authentication based on visitors IP address?

I would like to setup a Joomla website that requires visitors to login, unless they are visiting from a specific IP address or subnet.

Also, I would like the login to be LDAP based.

I would be hosting the Joomla site on my local network and exposing it via my router with port-forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

An authentication plugin is what you need. It is not so difficult as it may seem. In the "/plugins/authentication/" folder of your Joomla site you already can see authentication methods available;

- traditional Joomla (users in a database)
- gmail
- openid
- ldap

You can surely find on extensions site other auth plugins; or, if you have some PHP skill, you can build your own since all an authentication plugin has to return is success or failure.